# Ajax fadein effect for only the new posts

Tags: ajax

How can I add a fade in effect for just the new posts that are added when the 'load more' button is clicked? right now it fades in the new posts with the old posts together rather than not touching the old posts and just fading in the new ones

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".load_more").click(function (){
            $('.load_more').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.ajax({
                url: "loadmore.php?id=" + $(".ad_display:last").attr("id"),
                success: function(html){
                    if(html){
                        $(".main_page").hide().append(html).fadeIn("slow");
                        $('.load_more').html('Load More');
                    }else{
                        $('.load_more').replaceWith('There are no more posts.');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: On this question you appear to have undone an edit from @Brad, who is a moderator. Generally it is a good idea to leave mod decisions as they are. I am not sure why you are removing code from all of your posts anyway - please do not deface your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".load_more").click(function (){
        $('.load_more').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
        $.ajax({
            url: "loadmore.php?id=" + $(".ad_display:last").attr("id"),
            success: function(html){
                newPost = $(html);
                if(newPost.length){
                    newPost.hide().appendTo(".main_page").fadeIn("slow");
                    $('.load_more').html('Load More');
                }else{
                    $('.load_more').replaceWith('There are no more posts.');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

treat the "html" as a jquery object (DOM), then make it animated.

EDIT:

sorry, my englis is poor.

you want to add fade in effect for the new post.

make it into jQuery object.

html -> $("< tag >.......< /tag >")    (string to object(DOM))

let it append to the context and do the effect

not all posts >> $('.main_page')

your:

```
$(".main_page").hide().append(html).fadeIn("slow");
     ↑                                 |
     ╰----------------------------- --╯

$(<div class="main_page">
    Post
    Post
    Post
    "html"     <--- HTML appended here
</div>).fadeIn();
```

New:

```
success: function(html){
    newPost = $(html); ←╮
    if(newPost.length){ /
        newPost -------╯.hide().appendTo(".main_page").fadeIn("slow");
            ↑                                               |
            ╰----------------------------------------------╯
    }else{
        $('.load_more').replaceWith('There are no more posts.');
    }
}

<div class="main_page">
    Post
    Post
    Post
    $("html").fadeIn();     <--- HTML appended here
</div>
```

$(a).append(b);  //return a

Comment: provide some description also.

Comment: not to sure how to do that "treat the "html" as a jquery object (DOM), then make it animated." could you please explain?

Comment: The problem that @hasschi is trying to fix, is that you are calling `fadeIn()` and `hide()` on the main `".main_page"`, while what you actually trying to fade in is the new message. by `var newPost = $(html);` you would be creating a new jQuery object for the new posts, in order to be able to call the `hide` and `fadein` methods on it.

Comment: I understand what you said but i don't really know how to do it.. could you show me in you code that you posted above?